# How to prove that this module is not a finite A-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This question is from my module theory assignment and I am not able to form rigorious argument.

> Let A be a commutative ring and let  $V_i$ ,$i\in I$, be an infinite family of non-zero A-modules. Prove that $W=\oplus_{i\in I} V_i$ is not  a finite  A-module.

Attempt: I have assumed that let it be a finite module, ie a finitely generated A -module so there exists a basis {$m_1,...,m_n$}  which is finite. But I am not able to deduce any contradiction that how it cannot generate W.

Can you please give some hints?

Comment: First of all, it is important to use the correct terms: finitely generated is not the same as finite. I guess you mean finitely generated. Also, most modules don't have a basis. So $\{m_1,...,m_n\}$ is not a basis, but just a finite set of generators. Finally, about the solution: each element $m_i$ has just finitely many nonzero coordinates. So there is some finite set $J\subseteq I$ such that for each $i\in I\setminus J$, the $i$'th coordinate of all the elements $m_1,...,m_n$ is zero. It is easy to see that then the $i$'th coordinate will be zero for all elements generated by $m_1,...,m_n$.

Comment: So of course this shows that the submodule generated by $\{m_1,...,m_n\}$ can't be the whole ring, as there are also elements whose $i$'th coordinate is nonzero.

Comment: @mark How are you sure that each $m_i$ has just finitely many nonzero coordinates?

Comment: Because this is the definition of direct sum. The direct product is just the cartesian product of the spaces $V_i$. The direct sum is the subspace of the direct product which consists of the vectors with finitely many non-zero coordinates.

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much.